# Sabre Retrieve Trip API

Tags: sabre

I am participating in a travel hack. As part of that I would like to consume 'retrieve trip' API (SOAP) for a dummy PNR. I came to know that SOAP APIs are not available in test environment as per link (https://developer.sabre.com/io-docs).
For CAT environment, points are required as per link (https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_basics/environments)

Is there any way I can create a dummy PNR and retrieve it using dev studio or trip case?

Comment: "Points" is a verb, as in "This enptoint points to CERT systems". Just try your request using the  `sws3-crt` URL. No travel agency would be able to test code if we didn't have access to *that* test environment.

Comment: :) Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos. Let me try that.

Answer (score 0):

What the DevStudio says in the linked that you've provided is: *Sabre SOAP APIs are not available for calls into the test environment at this time. Check back often for an update.*
But this is only for testing in the API Explorer. The thing is that when you register in the DevStudio you are provided with a generic user which is allowed to use REST services in the testing environment in that page, but, at the moment, you don't have that possibility for SOAP services.

So, SOAP APIs are available in test environments, you just have to have credentials that are capable of consuming those services and do it using something compiled by you or testing tools like Rundemo or SOAPUI.

FYI, CAT environment does not exist anymore, it's been down for a few years now.

Regarding the endpoint, you could use https://sws3-crt.cert.sabre.com as sugegsted by Panagiotis Kanavos.